# Link Multiple Auth in Firebase while user is signed out

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have option of both *Email/Password* & *Google* Login/Signup.

Suppose user first signs up with Email/Password, logs out, later logs in with Google, the Email/Password entry gets replaced with the Google entry in firebase, but I want them to be linked instead. So if user again logs out and tries to login with Email/Password, wrong password is shown.

Firebase addresses this issue - `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.linkWithCredential(credential)` but for that the user needs to be signed in. But in my case user is always signed out when accessing the login/signup page.

So only way to check if Email/Password entry exists with the same email as their Google account is to get their google email, and for that the following code needs to be executed -

```
  AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

  UserCredential userCredential =
      await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  User? user = userCredential.user; 

  String email = user.email;
```

But the Email/Password entry, if exists, gets replaced on calling `_auth.signInWithCredential(credential)`

Please help me solve this issue to be able to automatically link accounts from both auth methods.

This is my current User account linking setting (since I don't want multiple accounts) -

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking a provider to an existing account requires the user to be logged in already, there is no alternative for that.

For this to work, you should detect (by calling [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/fetchSignInMethodsForEmail.html)) that you already have an account *after* the user signs in to Google, but **before** you sign them into Firebase with that account. Then when you detect the existing account, prompt the user to sign in to the existing account, and then finally link the new credentials to the existing account.

Comment: As of today 2024 march:

If you created your project on or after September 15, 2023, email enumeration protection is enabled by default. 
When email enumeration protection is enabled, your project has the following behavior:

...

A list of sign-in methods for a specified email address is no longer returned when calling the createAuthUri REST API or the **fetchSignInMethodsForEmail** client SDK method on all platforms.

...